# AES (aes-cbc-256) encryption/decryption with openssl expected output truncated

Tags: bash, openssl, aes, cbc-mode

I wrote a script. Please pardon that I am not an expert in scripting. 
Upon deciphering, the results gotten truncated.

```
[Message in text]: 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

message_input in hex: 303132333435363738396162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a0a
key: 788a1ca0bf1ab80f092841aabd77793f
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
c19f83afc1160ce81b0fc9906d513693386ccdd313b0f2884c698411441054e8
ciphered text: c19f83afc1160ce81b0fc9906d513693386ccdd313b0f2884c698411441054e8
IV: 7ecd3d63a8b74bb2f80d71a1c9d43359
deciphering ...

hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
key: 788a1ca0bf1ab80f092841aabd77793f
iv: 7ecd3d63a8b74bb2f80d71a1c9d43359
answer: 30313233343536373839616263646566
Deciphered Message in hex: 30313233343536373839616263646566
deciphered text: 0123456789abcdef
```

**The recovered `deciphered text: 0123456789abcdef`, `ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` gets truncated.** This is supposed to be AES-CBC. Is there an option I did not turn on?

Here is the ciphering:

```
    IV=$(openssl rand -hex 16)
    get_key_for_ciphering; # key_for_ciphering gets populated

    message_input=$(echo -n "${message_input//[[:space:]]/}") # remove spaces

    echo "message_input in hex: "$message_input
    echo "key": $key_for_ciphering;

    ANS=$(echo "0: $message_input" | xxd -r | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -iv $IV -K "$key_for_ciphering" | xxd -p)

    ANS=$(echo -n "${ANS//[[:space:]]/}") # remove spaces
```

Here is the deciphering (message_input=$ANS):

```
    get_key_for_ciphering; # key_for_ciphering gets populated

    ANS=$(echo "0: $message_input" | xxd -r | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -nopad -nosalt -K "$key_for_ciphering" -iv $IV | xxd -p) # -nopad -nosalt
```

Comment: You have `message_input=$(echo -n "${message_input//[[:space:]]/}")`, but that is more cumbersome than needed; you can just do `message_input="${message_input//[[:space:]]/}"`.

Comment: You have `echo "message_input in hex: "$message_input`, but you can just do `echo "message_input in hex: $message_input"`.  Same with `echo "key: $key_for_ciphering"`. And triling semicolons are redundant.

Comment: @Roadowl, how to solve the truncation problem?

Comment: I'll look at it again in the morning. My head isn't clear, I need to hit the sack. Btw., in the mean time try a simpler script where you leave the spaces intact.I.e., one where you have all references to vars neatly in double quotes, like so: `echo "key: $key_for_ciphering"`.  Also then leave off the "0: " part (why do you have that?).

Comment: Oh, and use `printf` instead of `echo` (do `help printf` and also `man printf`, though the latter is for the binary /usr/bin/printf, the former your shell printf, though for all intents and purposes they prob. work the same).

Comment: I print out to observe. For the "0: " without it, it does not work for openssl due to format issue.

Comment: Never heard of that. I'll look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Also in the new test script, leave out all the xxd stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing in your question, the problem is in the `xxd` command. When converting a hex string to binary with `xxd -r`, you have to use the `-p` to tell `xxd` that is a plain hex string (no line breaks).

When converting back to hex with `xxd -p`, line breaks are added every 32 bytes. Unfortunately, `xxd` doesn't provide a flag to not include line breaks (you could use `-c` to set the number of columns, but it's limited to a max number). There are many option to remove line breaks, but one is appending a `| tr -d '\n'` to your command, as shown in the example below.

```sh
IV=$(openssl rand -hex 16)
key_for_ciphering=$(openssl rand -hex 16)
message_input="303132333435363738396162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a0a"

message_input=$(echo -n "${message_input//[[:space:]]/}") # remove spaces

echo "Message: $message_input"
echo "Key: $key_for_ciphering"
echo "IV: $IV"

ANS=$(echo "0: $message_input" | xxd -r -p | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -iv $IV -K "$key_for_ciphering" | xxd -p | tr -d '\n')

ANS=$(echo -n "${ANS//[[:space:]]/}") # remove spaces

echo "Encrypted: $ANS"

ANS=$(echo "0: $ANS" | xxd -r -p | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -nopad -nosalt -K "$key_for_ciphering" -iv $IV | xxd -p | tr -d '\n')

echo "Decrypted: $ANS"
```

Comment: perfect ! I am often confused with data formatting. This is perfect help !
Thank you for guiding me, @Lucas.

Answer (score 1):

---- Edit: ----

Doesn't work, as shell-parameters cannot contain binary zero. Possible fix with filters:

```
#!/bin/bash

tohex () {
    perl -e 'binmode STDIN; while (<STDIN>) { print unpack "H*",$_; }'
}

fromhex () {
    perl -e 'binmode STDIN; while (<STDIN>) { print pack "H*",$_; }'
}

binInput='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

hexIV="$(openssl rand -hex 16)"

hexKey='788a1ca0bf1ab80f092841aabd77793f'

hexCipher="$(printf '%s' "$binInput" |\
    openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -iv "$hexIV" -K "$hexKey" | tohex)"

binResult="$(printf '%s' "$hexCipher" | fromhex |\
   openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -iv "$hexIV" -K "$hexKey")"

if [ "$binInput" = "$binResult" ]; then echo OK;
fi
```

---- Original: ----

I think your problem lies in hexadecimal conversion. Try using perl pack/unpack:

```
tohex () {
    perl -e 'print unpack "H*", "$ARGV[0]"' "$1"
}

fromhex () {
    perl -e 'print pack "H*", "$ARGV[0]"' "$1"
}

message='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxzy §"+!%/=()'
message_hex=$(tohex "$message")
message_cmp=$(fromhex "$message_hex")

if [ "$message" = "$message_cmp" ]; then echo OK; fi
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate with:
`ANS=$(echo "0: $message_input" | xxd -r | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -iv $IV -K "$key_for_ciphering" | xxd -p)`

and 
`ANS=$(echo "0: $message_input" | xxd -r | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -nopad -nosalt -K "$key_for_ciphering" -iv $IV | xxd -p)`

I used your code samples in some places, but it is still giving the same answers or at certain places, it changes the format incorrectly.